FullCalendar v6.1.8 in resource mode shows allDay events on each resource
I have purchased the premium package for FullCalendar and am currently running on v6.1.8.
I have setup the resource mode which is the main reason why I bought a license for FullCalendar.
I have ran into a limitation where allDay events are displayed on each resource column.
Here is the result I currently have:

Have here is the json of the allDay event called Training:
[
    {
        "id": 145,
        "resourceIds": [
            1,
            2,
            11
        ],
        "start": "2024-11-27 00:00:00",
        "end": "2024-11-30 00:00:00",
        "title": "Training",
        "editable": true,
        "clickable": true,
        "allDay": true,
        "backgroundColor": "#616161",
    }
]

I would like to have allDay events span across the whole resources for a particular day, i.e. visually have only one box for allDay events that span multiple days.
Am I missing something? Or is this not a thing in FullCalendar?

Events are per-resource. That's the whole point of having resources. You can, as you've done, allocate an event to more than one resource but that doesn't change the way it's rendered on the display - each resource is a separate column with separate events in it. See https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features if you want to get a change made. Bear in mind that this would not make sense as a feature unless the event in question covers all resources I think.

I understand the concept that events are per resource, but this is not necessarily the case, think holidays, bank holiday. These types of events should be able to span across all resources.

Well, they do - you've got Training written in all the boxes. So it's clear enough that it affects them all. You might think it's aesthetically more pleasing if it was written once and spanning all the columns - if so then, as I said, make a feature request to the fullCalendar project and see if someone will work on it. Or if you have the skills, contribute it yourself.

From a purely functional point of view, I'd say there's  enough there to convey the necessary information, it just isn't perhaps exactly the visual appearance you were hoping for. I don't work on fullCalendar but I might expect that it wouldn't be a highly-prioritised change, for that reason. Although if it's simple from a technical point of view someone might just pick it up and do it - hard to know from the outside, all you can do is ask.

P.S. You've mentioned this in the context of all-day events, but actually it's basically the same situation for timed events as well.

Fullcalendar does not have this capability at the time of writing. You would need to submit a feature request to the project and see if someone will build it.
